# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function hasAttribute() on a non-object

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I am getting error on line 18 while trying to get [siteadvisor.com](http://siteadvisor.com) rating. The error message says `"PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function hasAttribute() on a non-object"`. I have included ull php code that I am using to get the [siteadvisor.com](http://siteadvisor.com) rating.

```
public function getSiteAdvisor($domain)
{
    try
    {
        $callback_url = "http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/" . $domain;

        $curl_response = $this->curl->get($callback_url);

        if ($curl_response->headers['Status-Code'] == "200") {

            libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
            $this->dom_doc->loadHTML($curl_response);
            libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);

            $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom_doc);
            $tmp = $xpath->query('/html/body//div[@id="siteVerdict"]//img')->item(0);

            if ($tmp->hasAttribute('src')) {

                $tmp = $tmp->getAttribute('src');

                if (stripos($tmp, "green") !== false) {
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 1;
                } elseif (stripos($tmp, "yellow") !== false) {
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 2;
                } elseif (stripos($tmp, "red") !== false) {
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 3;
                } else {
                    $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
                }

            } else {
                $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
            }

        } else {
            $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
        }

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => array(
                'siteadvisor' => (int)$siteadvisor_rating
            )
        );
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'msg' => $e->getMessage()
        );
    }
    return $response;       
}
```

Comment: From PHP's manual on xpath::query():  If the expression is malformed or the contextnode is invalid, DOMXPath::query() returns FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem on the xpath query (just as Gordon has said):, And target the `alt=""` attribute instead.

```
$domain = 'google.com';
$callback_url = "http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/" . $domain;
// i know you know what do to just you can just adjust this
$curl_response = file_get_contents($callback_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($curl_response);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$siteadvisor_rating = null;
$img_rating = $xpath->query('//div[@id="siteVerdict"]/div/img');

    if($img_rating->length > 0) {
    // haystack
    if($img_rating->item(0)->hasAttribute('alt')) {
        $img_rating = $img_rating->item(0)->getAttribute('alt');
    } elseif ($img->item(0)->hasAttribute('src')) {
        $img_rating = $img_rating->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    }

    if(stripos($img_rating, 'green') !== false) {
        $siteadvisor_rating = 1;
    } elseif(stripos($img_rating, '') !== false) {
        $siteadvisor_rating = 2;
    } elseif(stripos($img_rating, 'red') !== false) {
        $siteadvisor_rating = 3;
    } else {
        $siteadvisor_rating = 0;
    }

    echo $siteadvisor_rating; // should be 1 for google :)
}

else {
    // no node is found
}
```

Comment: hi @ghost your code is working but it looks sometimes siteadvisor.com wont process the report as I tried by going to siteadvisor.com and did manual test. Is there any way to bypass the siteadvisor.com if it does not sent the correct info instead of stopping the process?

Comment: @KevinS may i know what happened to the manual test? what do you mean that siteadvisor.com did not process? what happens? and what will be the determining factor that indeed siteadvisor.com did made an incorrect info

Comment: I got the error `PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function hasAttribute() on a non-object in stats.class.php on line 750` so I went to `siteadvisor.com` and tried to get the test result of few of the website but I had to try several time to get the report. It looks like the error is throwing only when `siteadvisor.com` does not process the report for the domain. I have pasted the entire code of `stats.class.php` at `http://pastebin.com/SRArC6vg`

Comment: @KevinS my idea is, if the site somehow doesn't process, just use a simple shortcircuit on the code, just put before the `// haystack line`: `if($img_rating->length > 0) { // continue process } else { // error }`

Comment: as per your suggestion it looks like I have to make changes to `process.php` file in somewhere **line no. 193 to 200**. I have posted `process.php` file at `http://pastebin.com/wfguWPqp` can you please look into the file and let me know how can I apply your suggestion as I am very new to php? Thanks

Comment: @KevinS no, not the `process.php` but `stats.class.php`. `http://pastebin.com/SRArC6vg` before line `749`

Comment: if possible can you edit `http://pastebin.com/SRArC6vg` with your suggestion? I tried but I got syntax error

Comment: @KevinS i edited the answer, should give you the idea

Comment: I applied the code but still getting error **Error Gathering SiteAdvisor Rating Data. Further Processing Stopped because of a Failed Step.** I have created modified version at `http://pastebin.com/wrAwzbBM`

Comment: @KevinS wow, where did this error message came from? haha! the only error i got is from a slow internet connection, timeout, how to i replicate that one?

Comment: @KevinS sorry man, really can't replicate your problem, outputs `1` on my side

Comment: if you go to http://www.w3stat.co and try to lookup few domain names which are not in our database the error will show up.

Comment: @KevinS i don't know which causes the error by i tried something like: `nba.com`, `rottentomatoes.com` all resulted into error but on my edited code it resulted to `1`

Comment: I check the error log and it shows as `[04-Aug-2014 09:51:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function hasAttribute() on a non-object in /inc/lib/classes/stats.class.php on line 750`